# Explanation for grep-command

Tags: bash, grep

Would somebody please explain this grep command:

```
grep -v $'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
```

used as

```
cat sample.txt | grep -v $'\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'
```

sample.txt, having TAB-separated values, looks like:

```
33604305    2020-10-06                          ab  46  12  XX          2020-02-04  2020-08-05
41146190    2015-01-01                          ab  44  13  YY  s       2020-01-21  2020-03.20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, `$''` is a special way of quoting:

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially.  The word  expands  to  string, with  backslash-escaped  characters  replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
>
> ```
>             \a     alert (bell)
>             \b     backspace
>             \e
>             \E     an escape character
>             \f     form feed
>             \n     new line
>             \r     carriage return
>             \t     horizontal tab
>              ...
> ```

grep doesn't understand `\t` (not even under `-E`), so this is a way how to make it search for tabs.

Comment: Thank you. This means, that the grep -v command eliminates lines, containing seven empty columns besides each other, e.g. '\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'?

Comment: @StOMicha Yes, exactly.